# File created in subprocess.run not found by os.listdir()

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am using subprocess to launch an instance of ffmpeg extracting frames in a folder. Then I do `os.listdir` on that same folder and it returns an empty list; off course I would except to see the files created by ffmpeg listed.

Here is a minimal example

```py
import os
import subprocess

folder = 'generated'
subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'input.mp4', '-vf', 'fps=4', f'{folder}/%05d.png'])
print(os.listdir(folder))  # []
```

I can testify that the files are created while the script is running.

In the full example I am using ffmpeg complex filter to generate two output, I don't think that is the source of the problem.

Comment: If you add a `import time; time.sleep(5)` between the `subprocess.run` and the `os.listdir` call nothing changes? Because it **could** be that `ffmpeg` ends immediately spawning some other process, hence `subprocess.run` terminates and `os.listdir(folder)` returns `[]` because no file was created at this point, then the process spawned by `ffmpeg` completes creating the files. I have no idea whether the implementation of `ffmpeg` could lead to this behaviour...

Comment: Good point. Because the ffmpeg command takes a while, instead what I did is get timestamps before and after and output the difference, and I get about 100sec which is approximatively the time of the command. So it seems that it is not the case.